# How to add initial UIViewController to existing COreData app?

Tags: core-data

I am using model "Master-detail application" for my app and would like to set different initial view. Is it possible? I want to display UIViewController with menu buttons and one of these buttons should load the Navigation controller of the previous original initial view.

When I change the initial view in storyBoards UI to ViewController and link the button to NavigationController , the app crushes.

What would be the right thing to do?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What error do you get when the app crushes? It should be perfectly possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this code to the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)tellDelegateToFlip{
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    masterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:masterViewController animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And this method to the Initial view to call the master view:

```
-(IBAction)flipToMaster:(id)sender{
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
[appDelegate tellDelegateToFlip];               
}
```

And You're done!